# Send_keys not sending any text to element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

I'm trying to type a value into a textbox with the following element:

```
<input _ngcontent-nmc-c572="" type="number" name="bpm" placeholder="0" min="0" max="999" step="0.01" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
```

I currently have this code to do this:

```
bpm = 122
inputBPM = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/mp-root/div/div/ ... section[2]/div[3]/div/input")
inputBPM.click()
inputBPM.clear()
inputBPM.send_keys(str(bpm))
```

This code successfully clears the placeholder value of 0, but does not type bpm. Does anyone know how I to fix this? Thank you.